# x percent less likely

Tags: probability, percentages

Among other things, the text of a math question states:

> Employed people are **$25$% less likely** to watch $10$h or more of TV in a
> week.

Other data necessary for the calculation is given in a table accompanying the question. I have not provided it, as it is not central to the issue at hand.

The puzzling bit is the end result and a part of the explanation of how to arrive at it:

> Assume that the population of Belgium is $B$. Then the number of people who watch more than $10$ hrs of TV is:
>
> $$\frac{59.8 \times B}{100}  = 0.598B $$
>
> The number of people who are employed who are within this group would normally be:
>
> $$0.427 \times 0.598B = 0.255B$$
>
> But the employed group are **$25$% less likely** to be in this group, correct? How do we translate this information into a calculation?
>
> What this essentially tells us is that if the number of employed people who watch $10+$ hours of TV was **$25$% higher**, that is when their number would be exactly as we calculated above:
>
> $$X (\text{number of employed TV watchers}) \times 1.25 = 0.255B$$
>
> Let's rearrange our equation again to have × only on one side:
>
> $$ X (\text{number of employed TV watchers}) = \frac{0.255B}{ 1.25}  $$

What's puzzling me is: doesn't "$25$% less likely" mean $75$%, so the calculation would be:

$$ X (\text{number of employed TV watchers}) = 0.255B × 0.75?$$

Comment: Notice that "25% less" and "25% more" are not inverse operations of each other. "25% less" means "multiply by 0.75", whereas "25% more" means "multiply by 1.25". Their product is not equal to one.

Comment: Indeed... Does this mean the reasoning given in the quoted explanation isn't correct? In this case, one should either multiply 0.255B by 0.75 or divide 0.255B by 4/3, I think. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding calculations when it comes to probability, i.e. that "25% less likely" means "1 : 1.25".